# Updating XML node & attribute values in C++ using RapidXML

Tags: c++, xml, persistence, rapidxml

I have an XML file which is being used for storing camera parameters which will get updated in response to changes from the UI. With RapidXML, I can read the XML file, all elements & their attribute values. However, when I try to update the value of an attribrute/ element & save it, the file does not reflect the new value but shows the old value. I tried to test this concept on a small XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Kum</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

This is just a simple sample file with no attributes>
And this is the code I have.

```
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
std::fstream file("TestFile.xml",std::ios::in|std::ios::out);

std::stringstream bufferStream;
bufferStream << file.rdbuf();
std::string content(bufferStream.str());
std::vector<char> buffer(content.begin(), content.end());
buffer.push_back('\0');
doc.parse<rapidxml::parse_no_data_nodes>(&content[0]);

rapidxml::xml_node<>* rootNode = doc.first_node();
std::cout <<"<"<< rootNode->name() <<">" << "\n";
rapidxml::xml_node<>* firstNode = rootNode->first_node("to");
std::cout << "<"<<firstNode->name()<<">" <<firstNode->value()<< "\n";

rapidxml::xml_node<> *real_thing = rootNode->first_node("from");

if (real_thing != nullptr)                              
{
    real_thing->value("yuck");  // now that should work
    std::cout << real_thing->name() << real_thing->value() << "\n";
}
```

Here on is where I am confused. How do I save this change back to the original xml file. If I do,

```
file << bufferStream.str();
```

It not only does not save the new value, but seems to append the entire XML DOM instead of replacing the original element value. If some one can share a little snippet on how to go about this objective, I would appreciate that.
I spent the entire day looking through the documentation but also didn't understand the flags that get passed to the parse function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RapidXML holds an internal representation of the document structure, using pointers to the text data held in the `std::vector<char>` that you passed to `parse`.

When you modify the 'value of a node you're really just changing a pointer in the internal structure. You need to get back to a string using functions in `rapidxml_print.hpp`, which includes an operator for writing to a stream.

```
file << doc;
```

Why does it append? Because after your read the data, the stream position is at the END of the file. You could reset to the beginning using `file.seek(0)` but this won't truncate the file if your new data is shorter than the old.

The best approach is simply to write the data out to a new `fstream`, rather than trying to have one open for simultaneous read and write.

Also see here for some much tidier and faster ways to parse a file with RapidXML. [How to parse the XML file in RapidXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808022/how-to-parse-the-xml-file-in-rapidxml)