# C++, RapidXML: Parse large files

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

I want to parse a large XML File (33000 lines).
Following the structure of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Root_2010 xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="textpool_1.2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" lang="de-DE">
<Textpool Version="V20.12.08">
<TextpoolList FontFamily="Standard" FontSize="16" FontStyle="normal" FontWeight="bold" SID="S1" TextCharacterLength="0" TextLength="135">
<Text>GlobalCommonTextBook</Text>
</SID_Name>
<TextpoolBlock>
<TextpoolRecord CharacterLengthCheck="Ok" Status="Released" StdTextCharacterLength="4" StdTextLength="???" TID="Txt0_0" TermCheck="NotChecked" TermCheckDescription="NotChecked" TextLengthCheck="Ok" fixed="true">
<IEC translate="no">
<Text/>
</IEC>
<ExplanationText/>
<Text>nein</Text>
</ShortText>
</Description>
<Creator>z0046abb</Creator>
</TextpoolRecord>
</TextpoolBlock>
</TextpoolList>
</Textpool>
</Root_2010>
```

The element `TextpoolList` stores two parts.  Its name is stored in the first `Text` element. In `TextpoolBlock` are several entries stored. The element of interest is again `Text`.

I need to parse this file and extract all `Text` elements from the specific `TextpoolList` to export it into another file. Future prospect is to take advantage of the attributes of `TextpoolList` and scan entries added to `ShortText`. That's why I want to use some XMLParser.

I decided to give XMLRapid a chance. Since this file is quite large I need to switch some data from stack to heap. Since I don't really know how to do it I am asking you for some help.
I tried something alike to https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_in_c__/.

```
    rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* root_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* block_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* record_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* text_node = NULL;

    std::ifstream infile(file);
    std::string line;
    std::string tp_data;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
        tp_data += line;

    std::vector<char> tp_data_copy(tp_data.begin(), tp_data.end());

    tp_data_copy.push_back('\0');

    doc.parse<0>(&tp_data_copy[0]);

    root_node = doc.first_node("TextpoolList");

    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* textpool_node = root_node->first_node("Textpool"); textpool_node; textpool_node = textpool_node->next_sibling())
    {
        for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* list_node = textpool_node->first_node("TextpoolList"); list_node; list_node = list_node->next_sibling())
        {
            for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* block_node = list_node->first_node("TextpoolBlock"); block_node; block_node = block_node->next_sibling())
            {
                for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* record_node = block_node->first_node("TextpoolRecord"); record_node; record_node = record_node->next_sibling())
                {
                    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* text_node = record_node->first_node("Text"); text_node; text_node = text_node->next_sibling())
                    {
                        std::cout << "record =   " << text_node->value();
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Edit: I changed my code in a way I thought the data would land on the heap but I still get the same error to rather store data on the heap instead of the stack.

Thanks for all your ideas!

Comment: `This example doesn't work out.` - what exactly didn't work out?

Comment: `root_node->first_node("TextpoolList")` shouldn't that be "TextpoolBlock" ?

Comment: It is better to  use XSLT transformation for the task.

Comment: Generally that looks OK, although reading into a `std::string` rather than `std::vector<char>`  is cleaner, and also is heap-based. However, your traversal of the doc doesn't match the XML sample.  You don't traverse `TextpoolBlock`s, And you print the `->value()` of `TextPoolRecord`s, but they don't have one - just sub-elements.  Did you mean to print the value of their `Text` node instead?

Comment: If I want to read it in std::string some internal rapidxml thing fail.
Yes I wanted to print the value of their Text node but I didnt know how to access it

Answer (score 0):

Okay things finally work. This is my routine:

```
    rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* root_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* block_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* record_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* text_node = NULL;
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* list_node = NULL;

    std::ifstream infile(file);
    std::string line;
    std::string tp_data;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
        tp_data += line;

    std::vector<char> tp_data_copy(tp_data.begin(), tp_data.end());

    tp_data_copy.push_back('\0');

    doc.parse<0>(&tp_data_copy[0]);

    root_node = doc.first_node("Root_2010");

    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* textpool_node = root_node->first_node("Textpool"); textpool_node; textpool_node = textpool_node->next_sibling())
    {
        for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* list_node = textpool_node->first_node("TextpoolList"); list_node; list_node = list_node->next_sibling())
        {
            for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* block_node = list_node->first_node("TextpoolBlock"); block_node; block_node = block_node->next_sibling())
            {
                for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* record_node = block_node->first_node("TextpoolRecord"); record_node; record_node = record_node->next_sibling())
                {
                    for (rapidxml::xml_node<>* text_node = record_node->first_node("Text"); text_node; text_node = text_node->next_sibling())
                    {
                        std::cout << "record =   " << text_node->value();
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is some time left I try to find some workaround for that file reading fuckery.

Comment: Consider flipping your conditionals to reduce the large amounts of arrow code.

Comment: A few comments: #1 You don't need the `rapidxml::xml_node<>*` variables at the top, because you (correctly)  use declare them in the loop scopes. Apart from `root_node`, of course, which you should declare and initialise in one line. `rapidxml::xml_node<>* root_node = doc.first_node(...`

Comment: #2: your `next_sibling()` calls don't specify a node name, so you'll fetch the next sibling regardles of name.

Comment: #3: Your XML 'sample' is seriously malformed. https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

Comment: #4: Your file reading is super-weird, and will remove all newline sequences so multiline `Text` nodes won't work. Use `rapidxml::file`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808022/how-to-parse-an-xml-file-with-rapidxml/14524464

Comment: #5: Does your data format actually need multiple Text nodes under each `Textpool`? if not, you can remove the loop.